# Components does not contain a default export React

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, reactjs

Пытаюсь импортировать компонент CarList который находится в /src/components/CarList.js в App.js

Получаю такую ошибку

> ./src/App.js
>   Attempted import error: './components/CarList' does not contain a default export (imported as 'CarList').

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import CarList from "./components/CarList";
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <CarList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

CarList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class CarList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This will be the car list
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Перепробовал практически все с первой страницы гугла, что то не помогает. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: export default CarList есть в конце класса CarList? ну или export default class CarList extends Component {}

Comment: Имеется. Вроде проблема решилась установкой reactstrap. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно экспортировать `CarList` в конце файла `CarList.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CarList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This will be the car list
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CarList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно было добавить отступ  перед

```
export default CarList;
```

в файле App.js